# Using exceptions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, exception

I'm new to Objective-C world. What I have noticed while studying some iOS/Mac apps is that try -catch is rarely used, if used at all. 
For example in Java it is used almost all the time.
Why isn't it so common in Objective-C ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What’s the rationale behind the Cocoa exception policy - or why use exceptions only for programmer errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811620/whats-the-rationale-behind-the-cocoa-exception-policy-or-why-use-exceptions-o)

Comment: And a _great_ pair of answers by zneak and bbum here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648952/objective-c-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of SDK methods that take an `NSError**` parameter and return `BOOL`. To indicate an error they return false and feed an error back through the error parameter to communicate info.

Exceptions *are* used, but generally for cases in which there is some failure at the runtime level - e.g. some object can't handle a selector. Although it may seem contrary to what I just wrote, exceptions tend to indicate an error in design rather than a runtime error.

The `NSError**` idiom is all you need for things such as failed URL connections, data conversions, etc, where an error condition exists but a program really shouldn't be killed outright.

Start reading: [*Error Handling Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html)

Answer (score 5):

Exceptions in Objective-C are generally to be used for truly exceptional circumstances and almost always programmer error. To convey a recoverable error use the NSError** pattern.